# LINQ to Entities dynamic DbSet

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is it possible to specify the DbSet of a LINQ to Entities query at run time?

For example if I have a number of different DbSets that have a common property such as "IsExpired" could I pass the DbSet into the query?

So,

```
Dim query = From o In db.Products Where o.IsExpired = True
```

Would look something like,

```
Dim myDynamicName As String
myDynamicName = "Products"

Dim query = From o In db("myDynamicName") Where o.IsExpired = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is not possible becomes more clear when using fluent syntax:

```
Dim query = db("myDynamicName").Where(Function(o) o.IsExpired)
```

The function is a

```
Function Func(Of In T, Out bool)
```

and the type of `T` is infered from the `IQueryable Of T` that precedes it. (This is possible because `Where` is an extension method, so the IQueryable is its first input parameter). Thus, the compiler knows that `o.IsExpired` is a valid expression.

That means that `db("myDynamicName")` must either be specifically typed, which it isn't, or you must supply the type to the `Where` method. But that's exactly the thing you're trying to circumvent.